# simple algebra word problem if it takes $5$ people $7$ hours to wash one building than how long does it take $4$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It takes $5$ window washers $7$ hours to wash one office building, how many hours would it take $4$ window washers to wash the building?

This seems so simple, yet, when I work it out I get $5.6$ hours, which doesn't make sense, since you have less window washers it should take longer.

If it takes $5$ window washers $7$ hours, than it takes $1$ window washer $1.4$ hours.

Comment: It's a Dreisatz in German. The English translation is rule of three.

Comment: I dont understand anything you have said here?

Comment: Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication#Rule_of_Three

Comment: I think the best way to think about these types of problems is (for lack of a better word) in man-hours. Convert to how long it would take one person.

Comment: so isnt this simply 7 / 5  =1.4?

Comment: @italy not the number of hours must be divided among the workers, but the job must be divided among the workers.

Comment: If you are having a problem imagining this, imagine that you are paying the workers some convenient figure like £10 per hour, how much would the job cost? If paying the same hourly rate, the job will always cost the same no matter how many people do it. Then you may see how you can short-cut to measure the size in person-hours rather than in cost.

Comment: say $A,B,C,D,E$ are the window washers. $E$ asks $A$: "I do not feel well, can you replace me?" $A$ agrees and works $14$ hours in total. Say, others also ask $A$ to replace them. How many hours must $A$ work alone to do the whole job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could think about it like this:

$5$ people take $7$ hours to wash $1$ building

If you are dividing by $5$ you are dividing by the number of people

$1$ person takes $7$ hours to wash $1/5$ building

If you then divide by $7$ you are dividing by the number of hours

$1$ person takes $1$ hour to wash $1/35$ building

One person works at $1/35$ buildings per hour

If you divide the number of hours by the number of people you get something in the units $hp^{-1}$ - one fifth of a building takes $1.4$ hours per person for five people  - which is true, but not what you want to know.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

One person would need $5\times7=35$ hours.

Comment: Okay, but ijust cant really make sense of this, if it takes 5 people 7 hours, than surely if i divide equally between them i can work out the ttime taken per person, ?

Comment: Think of $5$ persons. Each of them washes a car (so there are $5$ cars) and this lasts $7$ hours. Now you have to do the same job on your own: washing $5$ cars and you need $7$ hours for each of them. Then you need $5\times7=35$ hours, right?

Answer (score 1):

The error in your reasoning is found in your last sentence.  If it takes $5$ window washers $7$ hours to wash the windows in the building, then if each window washer works at the same rate, each window washer takes $7 \cdot 5 = 35$ hours to wash the windows when working alone since each window washer completes $1/5$ of the task and 
$$\frac{7~\text{h}}{\frac{1}{5}} = 7~\text{h} \cdot 5 = 35~\text{h}$$
Therefore, it a single window washer completes $1/35$ of the building in one hour.

How much of the building will four window washers complete in one hour (assuming they each work at the same rate)?  Therefore, how many hours will it take four window washers to complete the entire building?

Answer (score 0):

So it takes $35$ man-hours to do the building.

With $4$ men, the job will take $\dfrac {35}{4}$ hours.